# Custom CRDs not getting deleted in kubernetes cluster, how can I forcefully delete it?

Tags: kubernetes

I can not delete an old CRD record and I get errors like "failed to call webhook"
This CRD and Wehbook are installed as a Helm package. When I uninstall Helm and Namespace everything will be deleted except an item in this CRD.

I tried to edit it and force delete it but I wasn't successful.
There is no finalizer field in it.
How can I get rid of this CRD?

Comment: Is the webhook server running for this CRD? It is defined in a ValidatingWebHookConfiguration resource

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you check whether your CRD is registered in **ValidatingWebHookConfiguration** by using `$kubectl get ValidatingWebHookConfiguration`